# DialogFragment in Nougat 7 has strange behavior in full screen

Tags: android, dialog, android-dialogfragment, android-7.0-nougat, android-7.1-nougat

I have a full screen DialogFragment. everything went well until I tested my app with the new android Nougat (7) version. suddenly I noticed that weird margins appears at the top and bottom of screen.

The parent layout is ConstraintLayout, but even though I tried to change it to LinearLayout or RelativLayout, nothing happend.

I have this code lines :

```
getDialog().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);  
getDialog().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(getScreenWidth(), getScreenHeight());
```

and this is the screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

any idea?

Comment: Hello MorH, I am facing a similar issue. Could you please let me know what fix did u apply to get it working ? Thanks

Comment: hello, sorry for the delay but i'll post it anyway for everyone..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution for this issue was to add the 'DialogFragment' as 'Fragment' instead of dialog.

I removed:

```
 dialog.show(fm, MyDialog.class.getSimpleName());
```

and added this code instead:

```
        FragmentTransaction transaction = iFm.beginTransaction();
        transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) iActivity.findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
        FrameLayout child = new FrameLayout(iActivity);
        child.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        child.setId(R.id.dialog_container);
        root.addView(child);
        transaction.add(child.getId(), iDialog).addToBackStack(iDialog.getClass().getSimpleName()).commit();
```

I added the DialogFragment above all content like dialog, but with simple fragment transaction.
that was the only workaround that I could figure and it works fine till now like charm :)